# Removing drive (or network name) from path in C#

Tags: c#, .net, path

**What's the most concise (but safe) way to remove a drive name, network path, etc. from an absolute path in C#?**

For example, converting

```
\\networkmachine\foo\bar
```

or

```
C:\foo\bar
```

to `\foo\bar`.

There seem to be a good number of questions already answered with regards to path matters, but I couldn't quite find what I was looking for.  My own first thought that came to mind was to use Path.GetFullPath() to ensure I'm indeed working with an absolute path and then to just use a regular expression to find the first slash that isn't next to another one.  However, using a regular expression to do path manipulation seems slightly dangerous.

Would it perhaps be wiser to get the drive letter/target network machine/etc, convert the strings to Uri, and ask for the path relative to the drive/machine, and then convert back to strings?  Or is there an even better approach?

Comment: I've written my own helper functions that deal with this. Just some `if`...`else` and string operations.

Comment: Then it may be nice to share those methods with us. Or else, your comment was useless :)

Comment: You could strip the string returned from `Path.GetPathRoot()` from the beginning of the path, but that would also strip `foo` from the network-path, since this is the share-name.

Comment: Or if you are doing much of these manipulations you may want to check out http://alphafs.codeplex.com/ which contains some additional path manipulation options to those provided by .NET along with support for extended paths (also not available in standard .NET)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use

```
string MyPath = @""; // \\networkmachine\foo\bar OR C:\foo\bar
string MyPathWithoutDriveOrNetworkShare = MyPath.Substring (Path.GetPathRoot(MyPath).Length);
```

Result for `C:\foo\bar` would be `foo\bar` and for `\\networkmachine\foo\bar` would be `bar`.

For MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx

**EDIT - as per comments:**

With "string voodoo" (which is NOT concise IMHO and thus NOT recommended) you could do this:

```
if ( ( MyPath.IndexOf (":") == 1 ) || ( MyPath.IndexOf ( "\\\\" ) == 0 ) )
     { MyPathWithoutDriveOrNetworkShare = MyPath.Substring (2); }
if ( MyPathWithoutDriveOrNetworkShare.IndexOf ( "\\" ) > 0 )
     MyPathWithoutDriveOrNetworkShare = MyPathWithoutDriveOrNetworkShare.Substring ( MyPathWithoutDriveOrNetworkShare.IndexOf ( "\\" ) );
```

Comment: But that wouldn't give the path he asked for in the network path sample above, since GetPathRoot would return \\networkmachine\foo in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the DirectoryInfo class?

Specifically DirectoryInfo.Parent and DirectoryInfo.Root may help at discovering the root directory so you can remove it from FullName

Parent:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx

Root:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.root.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about safety, but I'd personally put it into a string, look for a contains("\\") or ':' and remove them from the string by substringing around them.

Answer (score 0):

As of request, here is how I did it:

I've written a helper [class `PathHelper`](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=45085) that does what I think that the asker wants to know.

You can find the [library on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ZetaEnterpriseLibrary.aspx), the function I would use is `PathHelper.GetDriveOrShare`, in a manner similar to:

```
var s = @"C:\foo\bar";
var withoutRoot = s.Substring( PathHelper.GetDriveOrShare(s).Length );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work
this code using call recursion function

this only used for folder or file path

```
//unRootedPath= PathHelper.GetPathWithoutRoot("C:\foo\bar"); => "foo\bar"

 public static class PathHelper
{

     public static string GetPathWithoutRoot(string orgPath)
    {
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(orgPath))
        {
            return orgPath;
        }
        return GetPathWithoutRoot(new DirectoryInfo(orgPath));
    }

    public static string GetPathWithoutRoot(DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
    {
        if (dirInfo.Parent == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;//here recursion will stop
        }

        var parent = GetPathWithoutRoot(dirInfo.Parent);//Call same function (Recursion)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent))
        {
            return dirInfo.Name;//here start write path without root("C:\")
        }
        else
        {
            return Path.Combine(parent, dirInfo.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).