# Remove the "C:\" from 'Directory.GetParent' C#

Tags: c#

How do I remove "C:\" from a `Directory.GetParent` command in c#?

For example:

The command returns: "C:\Folder1\Folder2"

And I want it to return "Folder1\Folder2"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing drive (or network name) from path in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772520/removing-drive-or-network-name-from-path-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `Path.GetPathRoot` from the original string:

```
string root = Path.GetPathRoot(folder);

if (root != null)
{
    folder = folder.Substring(root.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove C:\ why don't you use `string.Remove` like so:

```
string folderName = @"C:\f1\f2";
folderName = folderName.Replace(@"C:\", "");
//Outputs f1\f2
```

Comment: its not always "C:\"

Comment: The question is formulated like it is, and the other answer already demonstrates the other way.

Answer (score 1):

try this it will remove your first three charters

```
folderName = folderName.Substring(3);
```